# Queue alternatives to MSMQ on Windows that supports large messages

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a system which uses WCF with Rhino Service Bus and MSMQ. I read that MSMQ has a limit of 4MB message size.

In the near future i would like to accomodate messages which are greater than 4MB in size and I am not sure how MSMQ handle large messages. I had a look on MSDN and there is an article on it but i am unsure how well it handles messages larger than 4MB.

Could anyone please refer me to good alternatives to MSMQ that is reliable and support messages large than 4MB.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Bus for Window Server 1.1 supports messages of up to 50 MB (unlike its Azure counterpart, which supports only 64 KB). If this size isn't enough, there's a pattern called [Splitter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2012/04/16/integration-patterns-utilizing-the-windows-azure-service-bus-part-ii.aspx) that allows to overcome this limitation. The Service Bus is owned by the same team that created MSMQ and offers many similar features, as well as some new ones. It requires a SQL Server instance for its storage.

There are also other options such as ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ, both of which are open source.

All of the above have WCF bindings, as well as a standalone API.